# "Google Play services are updating" message in SupportMapFragment when in release mode

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I have this strange issue with GoogleMaps.

When I'm in debug mode everything works fine, but when I'm in release mode the onMapReady callback is never called and the map display the "Google Play services are updating" message.

Another strange thing is that if I run an activity at the application start with a map it works, even in other activities.

This is my code in the fragment

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    FrameLayout fr = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, null);
    //views code

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return fr;
}
```

Comment: Did you figure why this is hapenning? I'm facing the exact same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't. It works in release mode only if i load a fake map in the first activity (the launcher activity). Maybe there is some bug related to others play services stuff

Comment: Facing the same problem right now! Any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading all my google-play dependencies to 10.0.1 worked for me. See like below:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I'm still using 10.0.1 versions and even downgrading to 9.6.0 or 9.8.0 doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to the proguard rules file

```
-keep class com.google. ** {*; }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: At the moment proguard is disabled, so it is not a proguard related issue.